# Bash script to load/unload pulseaudio module

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, pulseaudio

I would like to create a bash script that loads the `pulseaudio` loopback module in the event it is not already on, and vice-versa unloads it in case it is already running.

So far, I resorted to writing the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

MODULE_SEARCH=$(pactl list modules | grep -E "module-loopback")
echo $MODULE_SEARCH

if [ "$MODULE_SEARCH" = "Name: module-loopback" ]
  then pactl unload-module module-loopback
fi
if [ "$MODULE_SEARCH" = "" ]
  then pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=15
fi
```

which however does not work as intended since it turns on the module, but fails to recognize if the module is running and turning it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely doesn't work because your grep returns a whole line containing the searched pattern. Although you've tried to allow for that by prefixing `Name:`  in the `[ ... ]` test, you're probably missing some leading whitespace.

It's almost always better to use grep's exit status for things like this ex.

```
if pactl list modules | grep -qF "module-loopback"; then 
  pactl unload-module module-loopback
else
  pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=15
fi
```

`grep -q` silently exits with status 0 (true) on a match and with status 1 (false) on non-match. The `-F` switch just makes it a fixed-string rather than regular expression match - you don't need a regex here, and definitely not a `-E` extended regex.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!